# Anyone have good complete examples of using sitemesh and layouts in Grails 1.2?

Tags: grails, sitemesh

I had a grails 1.1 app working where keyword and description meta tags were dynamically generated.  There was a change in how that works in 1.2, but I cannot found good documentation.  I've tried numerous ways to make it work.  No matter what I do the resultant html gets something like

```
<meta name="keywords"/>" />
```

instead of the actual keywords.  The extra tags there are not a typo on my part.  So it also creates a bug in my rendered html.

Comment: Can you post your code for dynamically generating the meta tags?

Answer (score 2):

In Grails 1.2, there's a performance optimized integration to Sitemesh. You can use the old implementation if you specify `grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = false` in Config.groovy. 
There are several issues in Grails JIRA related to meta tags :

- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5605
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5598
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5696

Some of them will be fixed in Grails 1.2.1 .

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  Part of what I was wondering was whether the syntax has changed as well if you want the optimized performance.

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems in 1.2 with meta tags dynamically generates and found that the problems happened when the quote was followed by a $. If I put a space between the quote and the $ it worked like

```
<meta name="keywords" value=" ${keywords}"/>
```

May or may not be your problem...